# persistent connection in xpages and domino

Tags: xpages, keep-alive, persistent-connection

When I login to an xpage application from a browser the connection drop is done at 5 minutes, whereas when I access a traditional domino application the connection drop is around 1 minute. I am using session based authentication on a single server and the domauthsessid is being set in both the cases. I am using netstat to track the session. Why is xpage connection timeout different from the normal application? I do not have any keepalive setting on my xpage. For testing purpose on the server document I have set the persistent connection time out to 600 seconds. But either of my applications do not reach that timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout for an XPage session is 30 minutes and that can be set thru the application properties in each database. Above that the domino session timeout apply.

Comment: I am not talking about the session timeout. I am talking about the persistent connection between the server and the client.Since the connection is not up as per the settings in the server document, there is an additional burden on the server to make a connection and SSL handshake.